# VPN с промежуточными локациями

Tags: linux, vps, vpn

Сколько может пользователей использовать VPN с промежуточными серверами в 4 локациях.
Подключаемся к VPN Нидерланды, запрос идет к серверу --> Германия --> Швеция --> Эстония

Скоростью VPN 100Мбит\с.

Какое максимальное количество пользователей(участников) может быть? Т.е. использовать один VPN

Comment: Сколько угодно, пока ресурсов серверов хватит.

Comment: ну или пинг будет большой.